# Uncaught ReferenceError: exportid is not defined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

Well I have created an event so that a number of check boxes are selected and it should assign those checked boxes to an assignee if they are manual but if they are not, they should be. Here is the view function,

```
assignUserClicked : function() {
    var self = this;
    var modal = new AssignmentUserModalView({
            collection: this.getSelected()
        }).open();

    this.model.save({
        integrationlevel: 'manual'
    }, {
        type: 'POST',
        wait: true

    });
    var self = this;
    var refresh = function (model) {};

    this.listenTo(modal, 'ok', function () {
        self.model.fetch({
            data: {
                exportid: self.model.id
            }
        });
    });

    modal.open();
},
```

and the tmpl is below,

```
<div class="btn-toolbar pull-right">
    <div class="btn-group" title="Bulk Actions">
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-primary" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span>
        Bulk Actions
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <h3 class="pull-left no-margin">
            <%= name %>
            <small>-
                <%= exportid %></small><% if (integrationlevel== 'manual') { %>
            <small>-</small>
            <small class="text-danger">NON CHANGEABLE</small><% } %>
            <%= exportid %>
        </h3>
        <li>
            <% if (integrationlevel == 'automatic'|| integrationlevel== 'Automatic'){ %>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="ud_changetomanual" tabindex="-1">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                Set to manual
            </a>
            <% } else { %>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="ud_assignee" tabindex="-1">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                Change Assignment
            </a>
            <% } %>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

it gives me an error saying that exportid isn't defined, ANy ideas?

Comment: Create a fiddle with functional code

Comment: Yeah it's better formatted now, thanks megawac!

Comment: What exactly is a fiddle? I'm sorry I just started learning this...

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
self.model.fetch({
    data: {
        exportid: self.model.id
    }
});
```

sends `{exportid: self.model.id}` to the server as part of the AJAX request, it doesn't add `exportid` to the model as an attribute. Then later you're doing something like this:

```
var t = _.template(...);
var h = t(this.model.toJSON());
```

But there will be no `exportid` in `this.model.toJSON()` because no one added it; then the template function will try to find `exportid` when you `<%= exportid %>` but, since it isn't there, you get a `ReferenceError`.

You need to get `exportid` into your model's attributes or just into the template data. I don't know what approach would be appropriate in your case.

---

Keep in mind that [`_.template`](http://underscorejs.org/#template) converts the template to a JavaScript function and that function uses [`with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with) to make its argument object's keys look like variables. So when you say:

```
var data = this.model.toJSON();
t(data);
```

for a template containing

```
<%= exportid %>
```

The JavaScript engine will look for `data.exportid` and then, if it doesn't find it in `data`, it looks for an in-scope variable called `exportid`. That second lookup causes the `ReferenceError` rather than a `null` or `undefined` problem.

Comment: That would mean that I would probably have to check for exportid manually in back end. One approach I can think of is to write a post method to check for 'integrationlevel'.